# ltrim a substring

Tags: sql

I am using the below after select in a SQL query. Some of the results have a space at the start so I believe I would need to use ltrim to display as I'd like them.

```
SUBSTRING(mf_mm.DisplayName,8,15) as 'Name'
```

Could someone tell me the syntax to use `ltrim` in this case?

Comment: What database are you using?  You should tag the question appropriately.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? If you are on SQL Server, you can directly use the LTRIM() function

Comment: MySQL also has LTRIM() function

Comment: Apologies, I am using a SQL 2000 database

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I think every database supports 'LTRIM` Function.

Comment: @ 0Andrea - thanks I was just being stupid, the below worked.

    LTRIM(SUBSTRING(mf_mm.DisplayName,8,25)) as 'Name'

Comment: @AnkitBajpai . . . I think that is true.  Not every database supports `trim()`, though.

Comment: Yessss..! Now You are right. @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
LTRIM(SUBSTRING(mf_mm.DisplayName,8,15)) as 'Name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just `LTRIM(SUBSTRING(mf_mm.DisplayName,8,15)) as 'Name'` in T-SQL

Comment: Wouldn't he want to trim the whitespace prior to using the substring?

Comment: it seems that whitespaces are the result of substring (may be they are in the middle of the string)

Comment: Smart, I was thinking the data was like " someData" but to your point its most likely "sum data" and the whitespaces are introduced. I guess depending on the reason for the whitespace it could be lTrim(substring or Substring(ltrim

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(LTRIM(mf_mm.DisplayName),8,15) as 'Name'
FROM MyTable mf_mm
```

Or if your allowed just update the table.

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET mf_mm.DisplayName = LTRIM(mf_mm.DisplayName)
```